# Reactjs: Split function not working?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs

I am ios developer and newbie to reactjs. I am using this link

https://www.raywenderlich.com/165140/react-native-tutorial-building-ios-android-apps-javascript
to learn reactjs with ios. Everything works fine with the tutorial,but I got error on this line.

`const price = item.price_formatted.split(' ')[0];`

what's wrong with this line?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error you get ? send us an example to item.price_formatted value

Comment: TypeError:undefined is not an object(evaluating 'item.price_formatted.split')

Comment: Ok, so you try to split undefined variable, your "item.price_formatted" is undefined, try debug the way you get your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their should be a string value in "price_formatted".
try this:

```
const price_formatted = item.price_formatted;
const price=typeof price_formatted==="string" ?price_formatted.split(' ')[0]:""
```

Comment: var date  = 'Thu May 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'                      const price_formatted = date;
const price=typeof price_formatted==="string" ? price_formatted.split(' ')  :  "";
console.log(price); result is coming <empty string>

Comment: I have tested this example, and it is giving Me correct results. am I missing something?
`["Thu", "May", "21", "2020", "00:00:00", "GMT+0530", "(India", "Standard", "Time)"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 item.price_formatted.split(' ')[0];
```

This will always work, please check that `item.price_formatted` should have a value.

Comment: You are not getting any value in your props (item.price_formatted)